# Do I need two NIC cards if my UPS only has a network port and I need to stay connected to the internet?

Tags: networking, ups

[image: back of the UPS]

I need my computer to be connected to the internet and gracefully shutdown in the event of a power outage. This is an APC ES550 but it's a little old. It doesn't have a USB port that I can find.

Do I need to have two NIC cards in this scenario? One for the internet and one for the UPS?

OS: Linux Mint

Comment: Looking at the connectors it would seem that the ethernet port on the UPS is not a pass-thru port, so it is probably only used for signaling - thus you should not need an additional port for it - just configure the UPS on your LAN and plug it in to the switch.

Comment: oh I get it so the computer and the UPS would both be plugged into a network switch; for some reason I thought it would have to be plugged in directly; want to make that an answer?

Comment: It's best that he does not, given [user4556274's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1238312/401839).  Although davidgo's answer would make good sense if this was Ethernet, user4556274's astute observation demonstrates that not all RJ45 connectors are necessarily meant to be treated the same way.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Manual](http://www.apc.com/salestools/AHUG-9JU4RC/AHUG-9JU4RC_R0_EN.pdf) for a similar, but non-identical ES-550, the RJ-45 port labeled "Data Port" is USB, not ethernet.  A separate [ES-550 tech summary](http://www.apc.com/salestools/DFAH-8GLPTS/DFAH-8GLPTS_R0_EN.pdf) shows a layout identical to your picture—two RJ-11 above and an RJ-45 "data port" below—with the description "Use the supplied RJ45/USB cable…". So you don't want to connect *any* type of ethernet cable to this.  Instead, use the special USB cable provided with the unit, which has an RJ-45 connector at one end and a standard USB connector at the other end.

Or (given that the unit is old and you probably don't have the original cable), either order the appropriate part or don't bother with the USB monitoring.

Comment: Is there anything special about that cable that i need to know about? Any old Rj45 to USB will do?

Comment: You would have to ensure that the pinouts matched.  Since APC is using a non-standard connection, it would be safest to use a cable they produced for this product.  If any other manufacturer sells cables with the same connectors at each end, there is no guarantee that the wiring will match.  The pre-USB serial eia-232 signalling was notorious for incompatible cable pinouts, do the degree that a [guide](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~tcs3/tcs3/vendor_info/Digi/portserver_TS-Cable_Guide.pdf) for making cables to connect different devices runs to 150 pages.

Comment: AES? Mine's an APC.

Comment: I looked at my APC **BE-550G** (the same model that you link to), and the "data port" is a USB type-B connector (and it has no RJ-45 ports). The OP states he has a different model, an **ES550**. You've written an answer based on a manual for a different model.

Comment: @sawdust, the page I link to identifies the unit as "BE550G APC Back-UPS ES 8 Outlet 550VA 120V".  It includes a diagram showing an RJ-45 USB port in exactly the layout as the OP's picture.  And while I haven't owned this exact model, I've had a number of old APC units which had the RJ-45 USB port with proprietary cable.  I'm fairly confident based that my answer is correct, even if APC's model nomenclature is non-constant.

Comment: I did not say that your answer was not correct, but rather that it cites the wrong manual. The OP's photo looks like two RJ-11 sockets and the RJ-45.  The wrong doc that you link to has two RJ-45 sockets and a USB type-B socket (the "PowerChute USB port").  That's what is in the diagram I see in that doc, and what's on my unit of that model number  (previous comment about no RJ-45 is wrong).  The diagram and manual title do match what the OP has.   You don't deserve credit for a "correct" answer using the wrong evidence.

Comment: This is sad/funny.  First you link to the wrong manual but misidentify it (i.e. claim it's for the ES550).  Now you have the correct manual, but use new wording to misidentify it (i.e. it's "*similar*").  Even more interesting is the "tech summary" (which you also misidentify) which has the model number of my UPS, but has a RJ-45 connector (instead of USB) just like the OP.